# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.logging.log4j.simple.SimpleLogger incompatible with org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea, log4j

I have an Intelliji Scala Project ( Spark 3.3.2). I am building a fat jar with assembly.

1.I can build the fat jar and run it from the command line locally without a problem.
2.Jar contains code that is to be invoked as part of a UDF on a database
3.The jar runs correctly on the database server

However when I try to run the UDF it returns the following error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.logging.log4j.simple.SimpleLogger incompatible with org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.initializeLogging(Logging.scala:130)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:115)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.initializeLogIfNecessary$(Logging.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.initializeLogIfNecessary(SparkContext.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.initializeLogIfNecessary(Logging.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.initializeLogIfNecessary$(Logging.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.initializeLogIfNecessary(SparkContext.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.log(Logging.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.log$(Logging.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.log(SparkContext.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.logInfo(Logging.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.Logging.logInfo$(Logging.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.logInfo(SparkContext.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$.getOrCreate(SparkContext.scala:2714)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.$anonfun$getOrCreate$2(SparkSession.scala:953)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder$$Lambda$111.000000007C7BCFC0.apply(Unknown Source)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:201)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession$Builder.getOrCreate(SparkSession.scala:947)
    at ParquetReader$.main(ParquetReader.scala:21)
    at ParquetReader.main(ParquetReader.scala)
```

This is happening because the spark.internal.logging.initializeLogging is for some reason initializing a different logging class (`org.apache.logging.log4j.simple.SimpleLogger`) when invoked as part of the UDF than it does when I run it locally.

1. Can I control directly the actual class that Spark uses as a logger in this scenario and if so how?
2. Can I disable logging ENTIRELY at runtime with this setup, preferably with a config file that I build into the jar? I have tried to to do this already but it always defaults to `/org/apache/hadoop/log4j-default.properties`

Comment: Code reference: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.3.2/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/internal/Logging.scala#L130

Answer (score 0):

What version of log4j are you using/packaging? It should be the same as the one already provided by Spark which is 2.17.2 for Spark 3.3.2.

Edit: or you might have to exclude log4j dependencies from your fat jar to avoid conflicts.